# Textfield validation using matirial ui and react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form with some textFields which are required. How can I show error message if the user types less than 3 words?

```
export const Form = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

     return (
          <form className={classes.root} >
           <Container >
            <Grid container direction="row" spacing={3} >
              <Grid item>
                <TextField 
                    required 
                    id="firstName" 
                    label="First name"
                />
             </Grid>
           </Container>
         </form>
```

Comment: Hello Sandi and welcome to Stackoverflow. If you don't limit your question to specific problem and don't provide with current code(see [mcve] in Help for more details) your question will be probably closed by crowd.

Comment: I see that you have edited your question after skyboyer's comment but you should try a bit more... In your example the TextField doesn't have any state value linked. ( or the component does it on it's own ... )... Hint : You should try to use the `onChange=''`` event to do some logic on the value :)